# How to pass which object property should be updated in Java?

Tags: java, android, object, methods, arguments

I've got a little method in which I want to pass an object, and the property the method should update. For example:

```
public MyModel myMethod(MyModel myObject, MyClassProperty theProperty, String someValue) {
    myObject.theProperty = someValue;
    return myObject;
}
```

For this I of course don't need a method, but there's a lot more going on in the method. I just brought it down to its essence.

Does anybody know how I can pass the property of an object as a parameter which should be updated? (it's a bit hard to put this in words, but I hope you understand what I mean)

Comment: Without using reflection, NO I guess.

Comment: I think you are trying to force the language to be like JavaScript. What you want is possible using reflection but it is not the way you do things in Java. I'd rather redesign the code to be more standard and safe (using reflection hacks in real world projects is hardly advisable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Object myMethod(Object myObject, String thePropertyName, Object someValue) 
{
    try
    {
        myObject.getClass().getField(thePropertyName).set(myObject, someValue);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException noFieldException) {
        throw new RuntimeException(noFieldException);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException illegalAccessException) {
        throw new RuntimeException(illegalAccessException);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm! Although as @MisterSmith points out, this doesn't seem very Java-ish.. But hell, it works!

Comment: Ah, yes. Excuse me. Done!